# How to use quotation marks with bash regex?

Tags: regex, windows, bash, shell, syntax-error

I want to use a regex in my Bash script like the code below:

```
REGEX='^\s*-.*|^\s*file:\s*["'\''].*'
if [[ ${LINE} =~ ${REGEX}.* ]]; then
  # TODO
fi
```

If I execute this in the script in Windows it works correctly. But if I use shellspec (bash testing tool) it doesn't work. I read that Bash does not like the quotes for regular expressions around it. But if I don't use them I get an error because of this `["'\'']`. So how can I do this?

Comment: Note that Bash uses POSIX extended regular expressions, which don't include `\s`

Comment: So where do you get the error? In Linux? Then just use `REGEX='^\s*-.*|^\s*file:\s*["'"'"'].*'`

Comment: @Shawn Weird. If I remove them it fails. If I use them it works correctly

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I still get the error using your code (but your code still works on Windows). I dont use Linux. I use Git Bash with shellspec

Comment: Maybe it should be written as `REGEX="^\s*-.*|^\s*file:\s*['"^""].*"`?

Comment: Try this: `REGEX="^[[:space:]]*(-|file:[[:space:]]*['\"]).*"`

Comment: Regarding "I read that bash does not like the quotes for regular expressions around it" - at `REGEX='^\s*-.*|^\s*file:\s*["'\''].*'`, which I assume is the line you're referring to since it's the one with quotes around it, it's just a string being assigned to a variable, bash has no idea at that point that you're later going to use that variable in a regexp context and so whatever error message you're getting, it's not because "bash does not like the quotes for regular expressions around it". [edit] you question to show us the error message(s).

Comment: Note that you have `.*` at the end of your REGEX assignment line and then `.*` again where you use REGEX in the `if` and in both cases they are doing nothing useful as they'll match zero or any number of any char so you could just remove them (assuming you don't have subsequent code using `BASH_REMATCH[]`). The `{` and `}`s are doing nothing useful either and could also be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just tidy up your regex, fix your variable capitalization, and provide some sample input/output:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

regex='^[[:space:]]*(-|file:[[:space:]]*["'\''])'

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]; then
        rslt='matched'
    else
        rslt='did not match'
    fi
    printf '%-20s%s\n' "$line" "$rslt"
done <<'!'
-
  -
foo
file:"
       file: '
    file:bar
!
```

```
$  ./tst.sh
-                   matched
  -                 matched
foo                 did not match
file:"              matched
       file: '      matched
    file:bar        did not match
```

That seems to work, if you disagree tell us more about the issue.